# Handling large images in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, image-processing, mapreduce

How to split a large image using mapreduce ? I have a single image of size 6 GB in HDFS.

How to read a single block of data in hadoop?

Currently i am reading the entire image and splitted using commons imaging using a single mapper. Is there i can do it with multiple mappers ?

Comment: Your question did not specify that you require to process the image within a single mapper.. or instead are wishing to process pieces of the image in separate mappers - in which case you need to specify splittable input format

Comment: The image has to be splitted across mappers for processing and merged back. What do you mean by splittable input format ?